# How to delete existing version history of a node and create new versionHistory with latest updated node properties in alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I am trying to delete the complete version history of a node and creating a new version history with latest updated node properties, but it seems this is not going through.

Following is the code from alfresco javascript webscript:

```
promoVersionDeleter.deleteVersionHistory(node);

node.createVersion("Marking promotion as new version",true);
```

Here `promotionVersionDeleter` is a bean configured in `webscript-context.xml` to inject java webscript function in jsScript.

New version history is getting created with `node.createVersion`, but this is not having latest updated data.

Please suggest.

Comment: Any error you are getting in the logs?

Comment: If you just run node.createVersion("Marking promotion as new version",true); what happens? Does it have metadata?